# php is not getting any request from ajax type post and is it require to mention username and password in mail

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm working on contact page form to send emails.

I have written HTML form to get user details and performing form validations in *contactform.js* file. In the same JavaScript file I have written *ajax POST call* to call *contact_mail.php*.

I have found many similar questions over the internet but the problem is - in my local machine on form Submit button *php* is getting called, but this is not happening in remote web server.

If I avoid call to *contactform.js* by removing `class="contactForm"` from my form definition, *php* is getting called but I loose all the validation. :( If i call *contactform.js* by specifying `class="contactForm"` in form definition then validation are performed nicely but nothing happens on submit since no call to PHP.

I don't know what am I doing wrong...
Here is my code...

HTML form looks like this:

```html
<form action="contactform/contact_mail.php" method="post" role="form" class="contactForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
                  <div class="validation"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
                  <div class="validation"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="phone" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Your Contact" data-rule="phone" data-msg="Please enter a valid contact number" />
                  <div class="validation"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject" />
                  <div class="validation"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please write something for us" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                  <div class="validation"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center"><button type="submit">Send Message</button></div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
```

This is my javascript contactform.js file

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  "use strict";

  //Contact
  $('form.contactForm').submit(function(e) {
    var f = $(this).find('.form-group'),
      ferror = false,
      emailExp = /^[^\s()<>@,;:\/]+@\w[\w\.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$/i,
      phoneExp = ^\+[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{4,14}(?:x.+)?$;
      /*phoneExp = /^\d{10}$/;*/

    f.children('input').each(function() { // run all inputs

      var i = $(this); // current input
      var rule = i.attr('data-rule');

      if (rule !== undefined) {
        var ierror = false; // error flag for current input
        var pos = rule.indexOf(':', 0);
        if (pos >= 0) {
          var exp = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
          rule = rule.substr(0, pos);
        } else {
          rule = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
        }

        switch (rule) {
          case 'required':
            if (i.val() === '') {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'minlen':
            if (i.val().length < parseInt(exp)) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'email':
            if (!emailExp.test(i.val())) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;
           
          case 'phone':
            if (!phoneExp.test(i.val())) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'checked':
            if (! i.is(':checked')) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'regexp':
            exp = new RegExp(exp);
            if (!exp.test(i.val())) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;
        }
        i.next('.validation').html((ierror ? (i.attr('data-msg') !== undefined ? i.attr('data-msg') : 'wrong Input') : '')).show('blind');
      }
    });
    f.children('textarea').each(function() { // run all inputs

      var i = $(this); // current input
      var rule = i.attr('data-rule');

      if (rule !== undefined) {
        var ierror = false; // error flag for current input
        var pos = rule.indexOf(':', 0);
        if (pos >= 0) {
          var exp = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
          rule = rule.substr(0, pos);
        } else {
          rule = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
        }

        switch (rule) {
          case 'required':
            if (i.val() === '') {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'minlen':
            if (i.val().length < parseInt(exp)) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;
        }
        i.next('.validation').html((ierror ? (i.attr('data-msg') != undefined ? i.attr('data-msg') : 'wrong Input') : '')).show('blind');
      }
    });
    if (ferror) return false;
    else var str = $(this).serialize();
    var action = $(this).attr('action');
    if( ! action ) {
      action = 'contactform/contact_mail.php';
    }
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: action,
      data: str,
      success: function(msg) {
        // alert(msg);
        if (msg == 'OK') {
          $("#sendmessage").addClass("show");
          $("#errormessage").removeClass("show");
          $('.contactForm').find("input, textarea").val("");
        } else {
          $("#sendmessage").removeClass("show");
          $("#errormessage").addClass("show");
          $('#errormessage').html(msg);
        }

      }
    });
    return false;
  });

});
```

My contact_mail.php file

```html
<?php
/* send mail new*/
 /* start - send mail */

require_once('contactform/class.phpmailer.php');
require_once('contactform/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
require_once('contactform/class.smtp.php');
if(isset($_POST["Submit"]))
{
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $message=$_POST['message'];
   
        $body = '<html><body>';
        $body .= '<h2>Customer Enquiry </h2><br>';
        $body .= '<table rules="all" style="background-color: #EBF4FA;" cellpadding="10">';
        $body .= "<tr><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['name']) . "</td></tr>";
        $body .= "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "</td></tr>";
        $body .= "<tr><td><strong>Contact No. :</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['phone']) . "</td></tr>";
        $body .= "<tr><td><strong>Message:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['message']) . "</td></tr>";

        $body .= "</table>";
        $body .= "</body></html>";

$to = "receiver address";
$subject = " Enquiry Form";
$headers = "From: info@xyz.com" . "\r\n" .
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$res="OK";

if (mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers))
 {
     return $res;
 }
 else
 {
     return false;
 }
    header( "refresh:0;url=index.html");
}?>
```

Actually, I am learning php language at beginner level. 
What should do to send mail successfully and get success or failure message.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the submit form handler is not preventing the default submitted event. Try adding '''e.preventDefault()''' at the start of the handler.

Comment: Thanks for your reply !!! I added ''e.preventDefault()'' but still not working fine. My contact_mail.php file is ok ?. I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Your submit button doesn't have the attribute name="submit" and that's also what you check for in your php code, which is needed.

Comment: I've already tried the solutions given by you multiple times but couldn't resolve the issue. If the mail is successfully delivered to the mailbox it is done without validation, and if the validation is done then the mail doesn't get  delivered (only else part is working from ajax function means it just shows the error message) . Seriously, its very short time work but above code is taking a lot of time of mine. So please help.

Comment: If you use e.preventDefault() at the start of the submit handler, then there is only one way to submit the form via JS w/ AJAX here. That solves why you had to add and remove the "contactForm" form class, which was asked in the heading of this post. Check the value of the data before it's sent, then while it's sent data via chrome dev network tools, and also do a php var_dump($_POST).